# Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Drawing.Color

Tags: colors

I made app in C# that convert resistor value to color codes.
How to show color instead of text. For example, if I enter 15K it shows me brown,green and orange color, not text.

https://postimg.org/image/4tccjjnax/

When I set label15.BackColor=colours(res[0] - '0')
I get error cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Drawing.Color

Comment: Do not post your code as image, add your code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string to a Color with Color.FromName();

Example

```
label15.BackColor = Color.FromName(colours(res[0] - '0'));
```

Be aware you don't have { } Behind your else statement and only the first line will execute in else and the other lines will always execute.

*You don't have to but I recommend you to do it like this*

```
if (res.Count() > 11)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value");
}
else
{
    textBox4.Text = ..
    textBoxS.Text = ..
    textBox6.Text = ..
}
```

I also recommend you to give your textboxes logic names

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have problem with some values, for some values it does not show rigth colors!!!